# Appending multiple divs

Tags: jquery

Hi I've just started te jQuery,

I am trying sth like that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $newdiv = $('<div id="ball" />');
    for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
        $('body').append($newdiv);
    }
});
```

I know that iteration part's not right.. But how do I append 100 divs in jquery?

Comment: Very close, in your for loop `i:0` should be `i=0`

Comment: yea.. sorry I wrote that wrong! but that doesn't work too.

Comment: @user2045937 you need to clone it, once it is appended to DOM. it has the reference so appending again does just update the same element. `$('body').append($newdiv.clone())` and as sushanth mentioned id must be unique

Answer (score 7, accepted):

used `class="ball"` as id should be unique, *but you get the point, how to create 100 div*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $newdiv;
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        $newdiv = $('<div class="ball" />').text(i);
        $('body').append($newdiv);
    }
});
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/Uq2ap/

Answer (score 4):

**ID is supposed to be unique on your Page**. So use **class instead.**

Next , if you var `$newdiv = $('<div/>'` to create a div outside the for loop , it would only create a single instance of the div as it already is available on the page and cached.

So need to move the creation to inside the `for loop`

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        var $newdiv = $('<div/>', {
            "class": "ball",
            text: 'hi'
        });
        $('body').append($newdiv);
    }
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vTQ85/)**

Comment: AFAIK the trailing slash is unnessecary in `$('<div/>')`